# How come my UITableView is repeating rows after 5 rows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 7 rows in my database. I confirmed that all of the data is successfully coming over to the iOS side by NSLog the postArray which gives 7. However when I run my app, it will only display the first 5 rows, and then the first 2 rows instead of the 6th and 7th row from my database. Also when I NSLog the actual text from my 6th and 7th text view the correct text is in there... Why is it repeating after 5 rows? Thank you. Here is my code:

```
#import "DailyViewController.h"
#import "Post.h"

@interface DailyViewController ()

@end

@implementation DailyViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // View background
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(221/255.0) blue:(85/255.0) alpha:1.0f]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.org/getPosts.php"]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    postArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *nickname = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nickname"];
        NSString *squeal = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"squeal"];

        [postArray addObject:[[Post alloc] initWithNickname:nickname andSqueal:squeal]];
    }

    viewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < postArray.count; i++)
    {
        Post *postObject;
        postObject = [postArray objectAtIndex:i];

        UILabel *nicknameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 15, 320, 30)];
        nicknameLabel.text = postObject.nickname;
        nicknameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];

        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 42, 320, 0)];
        textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        textView.text = postObject.squeal;
        textView.editable = false;
        [textView setScrollEnabled:false];
        [textView sizeToFit];
        [textView layoutIfNeeded];

         UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 30+textView.frame.size.height)];

        [view addSubview:nicknameLabel];
        [view addSubview:textView];

        [viewArray addObject:view];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return postArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[viewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView *view = [viewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return view.frame.size.height+30;
}
```

@end

Comment: You don't setup your cell properly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You have no code to set the data for the cell. Cells get reused as the table is scrolled. So every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` must update the cell's state with data for the requested index path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` reuses the cells with the same reuse identifier, which means that when you scroll so that a row is scrolled out of the visible area, it will be used to show new rows. That's why when your 1st and 2nd rows were scrolled out of the view, they were used to show the 5th and 6th row.

You need to modify how you load cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // Add and setup views here.
    }
    //Add content to view here
    // e.g. cell.textLabel.text = @"Some text";

    return cell;
}
```

**BTW** You can use the property `textLabel`of `UITableViewCell`instead of creating a new label and adding it as as subview. If you need to have more control over your custom cell, then you should create a custom class and use a Storyboard file or a Xib file.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cell == nil)
{
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else
{
  [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
[cell.contentView addSubview:[viewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you are adding a subview to the cell's content view only if the cell is being initialized for the first time.

Rather, you should add/replace the subview on each call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.