# Managing multiple textview inside tableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, textview, tableview

i have a tableview which required three textview for description. i have made a prototype cell containing text view with tag 1000.
i want to reuse this textview but the text of the textview changes when i scroll.

Some time Faraz take position of haider textview and sometime zaidi take position of faraz.

i try to give them unique tag also but still it doesnot help me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *cellViewIdentifier = nil;
long section = indexPath.section;
UITableViewCell *cell;

if(section == kSocialStatusSection) {
    if(indexPath.row < socialResult.socialStatus.count){
        cellViewIdentifier = kCheckBoxItemCellViewIdentifier;
        cellViewIdentifier = [cellViewIdentifier stringByAppendingString:langAppendString];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellViewIdentifier];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        SocialStatus *  socialStatus = [socialResult.socialStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:kTagTitleCellLabel];

        //            NSMutableDictionary *obj = [socialStatusArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [titleLabel setText:[LanguageUtilities isEnglishLanguage]?socialStatus.typeNameEn:socialStatus.typeNameAr];
        UIButton *checkBox = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:kTagCheckButton];

        //            checkBox.selected = NO;
        if([socialStatus.selected boolValue]) {
            checkBox.selected = YES;
        }
        else{
            checkBox.selected = NO;
        }

    } else {
        cellViewIdentifier = kDescriptionCellViewIdentifier;
        cellViewIdentifier = [cellViewIdentifier stringByAppendingString:langAppendString];

        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellViewIdentifier];

                    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


        GCPlaceholderTextView *textArea = (GCPlaceholderTextView *)[cell viewWithTag:kTagDescriptionTextArea];
            textArea.placeholder =getLocalizedString(@"Description");

        textArea.delegate = self;
            textArea.text = @"FARAZ";



    }
}
else if(section == kSocialStatusProblems){
    if(indexPath.row < socialResult.socialProblems.count){
        cellViewIdentifier = kCheckBoxItemCellViewIdentifier;
        cellViewIdentifier = [cellViewIdentifier stringByAppendingString:langAppendString];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellViewIdentifier];


                    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        SocialProblem * socialProblem = [socialResult.socialProblems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:kTagTitleCellLabel];

        //            NSMutableDictionary *obj = [socialProblemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [titleLabel setText:[LanguageUtilities isEnglishLanguage]?socialProblem.typeNameEn:socialProblem.typeNameAr];

        UIButton *checkBox = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:kTagCheckButton];

        if([socialProblem.selected boolValue]) {
            checkBox.selected = YES;
        }else{
            checkBox.selected = NO;
        }

    } else {
        cellViewIdentifier = kDescriptionCellViewIdentifier;
        cellViewIdentifier = [cellViewIdentifier stringByAppendingString:langAppendString];

        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellViewIdentifier];

                    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        GCPlaceholderTextView *textArea =  (GCPlaceholderTextView *)[cell viewWithTag:kTagDescriptionTextArea];


        textArea.placeholder =getLocalizedString(@"Description");
        textArea.delegate = self;
            textArea.text = @"Haider";



    }
}
else if(section == kProblemTypesSection){
    if(indexPath.row < socialResult.socialProblemsTypes.count){
        cellViewIdentifier = kCheckBoxItemCellViewIdentifier;
        cellViewIdentifier = [cellViewIdentifier stringByAppendingString:langAppendString];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellViewIdentifier];


                    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        SocialProblemsType * socialProblemType = [socialResult.socialProblemsTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:kTagTitleCellLabel];

        //            NSMutableDictionary *obj = [problemTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [titleLabel setText:[LanguageUtilities isEnglishLanguage]?socialProblemType.typeNameEn:socialProblemType.typeNameAr];

        UIButton *checkBox = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:kTagCheckButton];

        if([socialProblemType.selected boolValue]) {
            checkBox.selected = YES;
        }else
        {
            checkBox.selected = NO;
        }

    } else {
        cellViewIdentifier = kDescriptionCellViewIdentifier;
        cellViewIdentifier = [cellViewIdentifier stringByAppendingString:langAppendString];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellViewIdentifier];

                    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


        GCPlaceholderTextView *  textArea= (GCPlaceholderTextView *)[cell viewWithTag:problemTypeTextViewTag];;

        if (textArea != nil) {
        textArea= (GCPlaceholderTextView *)[cell viewWithTag:problemTypeTextViewTag];
        }else
        {
         textArea= (GCPlaceholderTextView *)[cell viewWithTag:kTagDescriptionTextArea];
            [textArea setTag:problemTypeTextViewTag];
        }
            textArea.placeholder =getLocalizedString(@"Description");

        textArea.delegate = self;
            textArea.text = @"zaidi";




    }
}
return cell;}
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617151/how-come-my-uitableview-is-repeating-rows-after-5-rows and many others.  Table cells are reused, so the data unique to each must be kept in an array (or some other structure that can be indexed by row). Also, you must use different tags for the different text fields with the same superview.

Comment: by different tag, you mean to say i have to create three different prototype cell for textview and making each tag unique ? is it not useless if quantity of textview increase?

Comment: There can be one cell with three text views in it, but if you're going to assign each text view's tag property, those integer values must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

We can make do with an NSMutableArray object containing strings for each cell. You will have to fill the array with empty strings and use this info to fill the text field. It will be something like,

```
 textView.text = [textViewStringsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Since you're doing it programmatically within the view controller, you will have to set the view controller as your text view delegate. You can do

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)textField.superview;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

... Since you've the index path, you can map it to an array.

[textViewStringsArr replaceObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath withObject:textView.text];
}
```

This would be the basic idea. Start with a mutable array of empty strings and modify them every time the text view is updated by replacing the original text with the new text. Hope this helps.