# UITableViewCell is repeating after every 5th cell (Before you mark as duplicate kindly read the whole quest )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

(Before you mark as duplicate you have to read the whole question and I am posting this cause I din't found the relevant and proper solution also need the solution in swift)

I have created one demo project and load and displayed name and area from array on custom cell.
I have noticed that after every 5th cell means 6th row is repeating with contents of 0th cell 
for e.g.

the demo code is given below

```
class demoTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var name : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var area : UILabel!
}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrDemo.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        var cell : demoTableCell = demoTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)! as! demoTableCell

            cell.name.text = (arrDemo.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Name") as? String
            cell.area.text = (arrDemo.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Area") as? String

            if indexPath.row == 0{
                cell.name.isHidden = true
            }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

As I hide the first label on 0th cell so I found that 6th row is also effected with implemented functionality of 0th cell. It means that also hide label1 of every 6th cell as I have attached the screenshot below so you can get the exact issue (This issue happened only if table view is scrollable)

[image]
[image]

As I have try to solve this issue from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617151/how-come-my-uitableview-is-repeating-rows-after-5-rows) also but facing the same issue and cannot find the proper solution, and I am stuck here.

Comment: Note that `if indexPath.row == 0{cell.name.isHidden = true}` should have also a `else {cell.name.isHidden = false}` because cells are reused. Also, avoid using `NSDictionary`, prefers Dictionary.

Comment: I would rather use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` instead of `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` for performance reasons

Comment: @Larme if I am using following thing then how can I manage?
`if (row == 0){
var movingBannerView:LCBannerView! 
for i in 0..<arrCarListImages.count{
urls.add((((arrCarListImages.object(at: i)) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "car_image")))
            }
            if movingBannerView == nil {
                movingBannerView = LCBannerView()
                movingBannerView = LCBannerView(frame: frame,delegate: self,imageURLs: urls ,timerInterval: Int(3.0))
                movingBannerView.pageDistance = 20.0
                cell.addSubview(movingBannerView)
            }
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember - the cells are being reused.

You hide the cell, but you never explicitly unhide the cell

When you come to row 6, you are re-using the cell that was at row 0, and isHidden = true

All you need to do is extend your check, and hide the rows that you need to be hidden, and explicitly show the cells that you need to see.  If you also have a moving banner that you add - you will also need to check to see if it's been loaded, and remove it if not required.  Remember - it may not be row 6 - that's just how it works out with the current screensize

If you do have significant differences between the cells you want to use, you might be better using two different classes - and then you don't have to think about hiding labels

```
class demoTableCell: DemoTableCellNormalRow {
    @IBOutlet var name : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var area : UILabel!
}

class demoTableCell: DemoTableCellFirstRow {
    @IBOutlet var area : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var movingBannerView : LCBannerView!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    if row == 0 {
        var cell : demoTableCell = demoTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)! as! DemoTableCellFirstRow

        cell.area.text = (arrDemo.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Area") as? String

        // populate the bannerview which already exists, or create a new one

        return cell
    } else {
        var cell : demoTableCell = demoTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)! as! DemoTableCellNormalRow

        cell.name.text = (arrDemo.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Name") as? String
        cell.area.text = (arrDemo.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Area") as? String

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: but can we prevent that cell 0 must not reusing at row 6 or anywhere ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to prevent the cell from being reused.  If there is something special about that row, you could have two different cell classes used within your table - but if the only difference is hiding on label, then it is hard to see why you would want to

Comment: Please read my last comment posted on question. I want to do exactly like this and when cell is repeating then this movingBanner view is repeating and I can't prevent that view to load at 6th row

Comment: it's just more of the same answer :-)  When you are reusing the cells, anything you change first time round needs to be removed or updated before you use it again.  You can either explicitly remove the banner from every row where you don't need it, or create two versions of the cell which you can use - I will update my answer to show you what I mean...

Answer (score 4):

Cells are reused, you have to make sure that every UI element is set to a defined state.

You are using an `if` clause but there is no `else` case or a default value.

Simple solution:

Just replace

```
 if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.name.isHidden = true
 }
```

with

```
 cell.name.isHidden = indexPath.row == 0
```

this sets the `hidden` property always to a defined state.

---

And the usual *dont's*

- Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift.
- Do not `valueForKey` unless you really need KVC (actually here you don't).

Comment: This is just an example to hide label in custom cell, but actually I need to add a view to cell 0 but its repeating on cell 6 so can I avoid this issue

"cell.name.isHidden = indexPath.row == 0"
this is easy but it cannot applied while adding a view to cell
so how can I solve this issue.?

Comment: As explained in the simple example if you change the state of an UI element conditionally you have to set the state to a default or defined value if the condition evaluates to `false`. Be aware that you can create multiple different cells in the same table view.

Answer (score 2):

Implement prepareForReuse in your cell class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
     name.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: self.name.isHidden = false