# Why are the icons from my cell changing after scrolling?

Tags: swift

I made a list where a user can see if an **event** is **started**, **paused** or **stopped**.

An event which is just created has no icon and no state and is returned with a **created timestamp**.

The problem which I have is that blank cells without an icon change their icon to "stop" when scrolling out of the view.

```
events.asObservable()
            .bind(to:tableView.rx.items) { (tableView, row, event) in
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventCell") as! EventCell
                cell.detailLabel.text = "created: \(self.dateFormat.string(from: event.created!)) Uhr"
                cell.titleLabel.text = event.name
                if let date = event.started {
                    cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: "start") 
                    var dateStr = "started: \(self.dateFormat.string(from: date))"

                    if let paused = self.isPaused(event: event) {
                        if paused {
                            dateStr = "\(dateStr), paused"
                            cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
                        }
                    }

                    if let dateEnded = event.ended {
                        dateStr = "\(dateStr), ended: \(self.dateFormat.string(from: dateEnded))"
                        cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: "stop")
                    }
                }
                return cell

            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

What is happening?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47093236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because of cell reuse. You should probably override the `prepareForReuse` method in `EventCell` and set the image to an initial image or nil before it's being reused at the next `cellForRow` (or `cellForItem` in UICollectionView) to fix this issue.

```
class EventCell: UITableViewCell { // (or UICollectionViewCell if issue is in UICollectionView)
    //...
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageView.image = nil // or a default placeholder image.
    }
}
```

Alternate Approach: You could also fix this issue in the `cellForRow` in `UITableView` (or `cellForItem` in `UICollectionView`) method by setting the `imageView.image` to nil or the placeholder image at the top and proceed.

For UITableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    cell.imageView.image = nil // or a default placeholder image.
    //...
    return cell
}
```

For UICollectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    cell.imageView.image = nil // or a default placeholder image.
    // ...
    return cell
}
```